# Hard and dry, limp and moist, what can I be?

Tags: riddle

> I go into your mouth hard and dry
> And I come out limp and moist
> I'm often a pinkish color
> But of course, my color may differ
> As may my size and flavor
> Indeed, my very texture might vary
> As well as the smell I carry

I'm not obscene
What can I be?

(Edit: I realized that this question has some suggestive themes, though I did not intend it to. I apologize to those whom I may have offended.)

Comment: Seems this riddle was taken the wrong way... oof :\

Comment: One question about the riddle, you mention that color, shape size texture and smell may vary. Is that in the same single item. or are you referencing a group of items?

Comment: It's a single item, but the size, flavor, color, and (sometimes) the texture itself might differ.

Comment: An updated version of [Riddle 25](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exeter_Book_Riddle_25), I see...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is inappropriate.

Comment: I gave you a +1 for the entertainment value ;)

Comment: Interestingly, I've read this "joke" in a jokes app quite some time ago. Of course, worded differently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are

> chewing gum.

I go into your mouth hard and dry
And I come out limp and moist

> You put it into your mouth when it's hard and unchewed, and it comes out all chewed up.

I'm often a pinkish color
But of course, my color may differ

> This is a reference to bubblegum, which is quite often a pink color and what a lot of people associate with gum.

As may my size and flavor
Indeed, my very texture might vary
As well as the smell I carry

> Gum comes in all shapes, sizes, and flavors.

Answer (score 1):

> A jawbreaker

> I go into your mouth hard and dry; they start hard and dry
>  And I come out limp and moist: the core is usually a gum center.
>  I'm often a pinkish color: again referencing the gum center.
>  But of course, my color may differ: many jawbreakers come in different colored layers
>  As may my size and flavor: those different colored layers tend to change flavor
>  Indeed, my very texture might vary: the outside is usually a bit powdery, then there's the hard layers. Finally the gum center.
>  As well as the smell I carry: this might reference the layers again?

Comment: Actually did not know jawbreakers had a gum center. Your answer is super close, though!